# How Can I Resolve this error for Installing npm install --save react-html-table-to-excel this packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error for installing "npm install --save react-html-table-to-excel  " this package.

PS C:\Users\Dev03\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\usermanagement> npm install react-html-table-to-excel
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! While resolving: usermanagement@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.x.x" from react-html-table-to-excel@2.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-html-table-to-excel
npm ERR!   react-html-table-to-excel@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Dev03\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dev03\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-27T11_45_28_139Z-debug.log

Comment: react-html-table-to-excel has peer dependency of react 15.x but you have react 17.x installed. Either downgrade your react (not recommended, other packages will run into issues if you have more), or use another package as it is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

`react-html-table-to-excel` requires react 15.

https://github.com/zsusac/ReactHTMLTableToExcel/blob/master/package.json#L42

Either you will have to downgrade to react 15, or you could try to force the installation with the `legacy-peer-deps` flag like this:

`npm install react-html-table-to-excel --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm install --save react-html-table-to-excel --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: Yes...Now Its Working...Thank You @Izhan Yameen